# what can i use in place of ESXi, if i want to use ubuntu based solution only?

Tags: 14.04, server, virtualization, openstack, esx

I am reading, reading but not able to figure, How can i build a container and VM cloud with 3 old PCs?? I guess I am very much confused on very first step that, WITHOUT ESXi do I need full ubuntu server base install first?

will the base ubuntu install work as ESXi? and then what software will I need to run VMs and containers on top of that?

How can I partition disks so that they can be used as a pool?

I guess openstack utilities will be used to manage the whole thing, but that is not my current worry. (I also want to manage all 3 PCs base OS from a 4th diff PC, like vSphere I guess...)

any links, guides etc. will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to review information on [Openvz](https://openvz.org/Main_Page), or Virtuozzo(a commercial product). It's the Linux equivalent of VMWare and has been around for a while, though it's Kernel is based on Red Hat Linux. If I read the information correctly, it also permits for container deployments using a version of lxc.

For physical machine deployment, you could look at Ubuntu's [MAAS](https://www.ubuntu.com/server/maas).

For container deployment only, you could look at [LXD](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/03/14/the-lxd-2-0-story-prologue/), the link is the start of a set blogs from Stéphane Graber, who is the technical lead for LXD at Canonical Ltd.

**Will the base Ubuntu install work as ESXi**
In a sense, it provides the core operating system for the virtual environments or management software to run. In addition, to the core system, you should select openssh server, for remote shell access to the system, as ssh'ng to other systems will be required.

**How can I partition disks so that they can be used as a pool?**
You best option would be to leave your target space unpartitioned to begin with and install `zfsutils-linux`. Though, using zfs will also allow the creation of Loop devices to take advantage of the benefits of zfs.

Of course there are many more options available.

I hope this provides some small assistance.

Comment: thx. openstack is big and complex, i guess it is difficult to get in, and it may be easy once you have done a few....